Use FoxPro report in .NET
I have a Visual FoxPro (frx) report that is formatted to contain values from a query. It is planned to use this format as a template for PDF reports.
Is there a way to use it in a .NET application without any paying third party tool?

In my case, we had SQL server as the data source, I created a VFP executable that contains all the reports (FRX) and queries for them, .Net application (ASP.Net MVC with C# in my case) sends parameters for the report query and get the PDF upon completion. An FRX is a VFP table that could be included in a VFP executable or kept as separate. Do you have VFP to start with?

Yes, I do, please nay help would be great.

If you can give me your email address, I can send you part of the C# code and VFP and explain the details a bit more (possibly at or after the weekend)

How can I do that?

Give me your email address and I would share stuff with you.

@CetinBasoz Why you don't kindly post it here so everyone can learn.

@KJ I did not fully understand your comment, from what I've seen, yes, it takes some images and text from a DB and fills that preformatted report fields then it calls novapdf in order to generate it and be able to print it, the issue is they want to automate that process, there is more than 20,000 of these.

@KJ, your understanding is incomplete. VFP has the ability to write that 'layout' result as a PDF directly.

I regretted posting here, it is not very easy to explain in a limited space for everybody. Anyway, I posted the related parts in C# and VFP.

C# side collects the parameters, including the report Id to generate and save it to a .DAT file as XML.
Then WGReport.exe is called passing the .dat name as a parameter.
VFP exe WGReport, opens that .DAT file, decrypts (I send the content encrypted), runs the report, generates the PDF.
   public JsonResult GenerateReport(string reportId)
    {
        var downloadInfo = new DownloadInfo
        {
            NoData = true,
            Message = "",
            FileName = "",
            Id = ""
        };

    // Prepare reportParameters - as XML, report definition object ... 
        
        var result = CallReportCreator(ds.EncryptReportParameters(reportParameters), pdfName);
        var reportName = report.ReportName;

        if (result)
        {
            downloadInfo.NoData = false;
            downloadInfo.Message = Url.Action("DownloadReport", "Report", new { reportid = pdfId, filename = report.ReportName });
            downloadInfo.FileName = report.ReportName;
            downloadInfo.Id = pdfId;
        }
        else
        {
            downloadInfo.NoData = true;
            downloadInfo.Message = "No data found in given period.";
            downloadInfo.FileName = "";
            downloadInfo.Id = "";
        }
        
        return Json(downloadInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private bool CallReportCreator(string parameters, string resultPdf)
    {
        var exeName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "WGReport.exe");
        var datName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".dat");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(datName, parameters);
        ShellExecMyProcess(exeName, string.Format(@"""{0}""", datName), true, 60);
        //System.IO.File.Delete(datName);
        return System.IO.File.Exists(resultPdf);
    }

    private string ShellExecMyProcess(string fileName, string arguments, bool waitToExit = true, int timeOut = 60)
    {
        bool processExited = false;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            psi.FileName = fileName;
            psi.Arguments = arguments;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);

            Process p = new Process();
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += (s, e) =>
            {
                processExited = true;
            };
            p.StartInfo = psi;


            p.Start();
            if (waitToExit)
            {
                while (!processExited && DateTime.Now < start.AddSeconds(timeOut))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                return "success";
            }
            else
            {
                return "process called";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Format("error: [{0}]\n{1}", fileName, e.Message);
        }
    }

On VFP side main looks like:
Lparameters tcFileName

#include atrack.h
Set Exclusive Off
Set Safety Off

On Error Do ErrHandle With ;
    ERROR( ), Message( ), Message(1), Program( ), Lineno( )
Return RunReport(m.tcFileName)
On Error

Procedure RunReport(m.tcFileName)
    Local lcResult
    lcResult = report_ForWG(m.loReportParameters)
    Return m.lcResult
Endproc

report_ForWG(toReportParameters) is the process, running the report with given parameters and returning result string. In my case, lcResult is either 'No data found in given period.' or the name of the PDF filename that gets generated.
